# Check if array of object value exist in another array but different length

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have 2 array of object, just want to check b exist in a, if yes add a new property. but the length of b is dynamic. I will got error of undefined of b.

```
var a = [{name:'john'},{name:'james'},{name:'jordan'},{name:'joe'}];
var b = [{name:'john'},{name:'joe'}];

var exist = 0;
var c = _.map(a,function(result,i){
    exist = b[i].name.indexOf(a.name) > -1 ? exist = 1 : exist = 0;

    return _.extend({},c,{'exist':exist});
});
```

any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate over b objects and for each of them check if they exists in A, like in the following example.

```js
    var a = [ { _id: '5815adb4badf3f311a2cd25b', username: 'david&jane' },
    { _id: '5815e40e136c8e33b65b3478', username: 'david+jane' } ];
    var b = [ { username: 'david&jane' },
              { username: 'david<3jane' },
              { username: 'david+jane' },
              { username: 'davidjane' } 
    ]
    var c = [];

    b.forEach(function(user) {
      var exists = false;
      for (let i=0; i<a.length && !exists; i++){
          exists = a[i].username === user.username ;
      }
      
      c.push(Object.assign({},user,{exists}));
    });

    console.log(c);
```

Comment: what is Object.assign, never seen them before, ES6?

Comment: Yea, suppose to act like your `_.extend({},c,{'exist':exist});`

Comment: assume my a has extra id field, then I can't apply ur solution, mind to take a look why? http://pastebin.com/1PTPZpkc

Comment: instead of use Object.assign, can use lodash? too risky to use ES6 for old browser.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin I updated the example with the objects with the id property and I can't see a problem. And yea I dont see why you wont be able to use loadash

Comment: ah my bad it worked now, maybe I miss replace some of the variables. 1 more question, does !exist in the for loop required?

Comment: first of for efficiency - if I already found an occurrence of it - no need to keep looking. second if I already found an occurrence I don't want that the next iteration will make it false again.

Comment: means it's optional?

Answer (score 1):

First `stringify` `a` array. Loop through `b` and create a dynamic regex to test on `a` if the test matches do your stuff.

Hope this helps!

```js
var a = [{name:'john'},{name:'james'},{name:'jordan'},{name:'joe'}];
var b = [{name:'john'},{name:'joe'}, {name:'hello'}];

var strA = JSON.stringify(a)

var result = b.map((el) => {
  var elStr = JSON.stringify(el)
  var regex = new RegExp(elStr, 'g')
  if(regex.test(strA))
     return Object.assign({}, el, {exist: 1})
  return Object.assign({}, el, {exist: 0})
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I did not downvote but this seems too complicated for me.

Comment: It is the most simplest answer with one loop.

Comment: You just need to loop through `b`. The other answer will loop through `a` for each element in `b` which is really costly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.every` to check that every object in `b` is also in `a`, and in the callback you could use `Array.some` to check `a` for keys and values

```js
var a = [{name:'john'},{name:'james'},{name:'jordan'},{name:'joe'}];
var b = [{name:'john'},{name:'joe'}];

var exist = b.every( (o) => {
    let k = Object.keys(o)[0];
    return a.some( p => k in p && p[k] === o[k]);
});

console.log(exist)
```

If you want to add properties, you can do that as well

```js
var a = [{name:'john'},{name:'james'},{name:'jordan'},{name:'joe'}];
var b = [{name:'john'},{name:'joe'}];

var c = b.map( (o) => {
    let k = Object.keys(o)[0];
    return o.exist = a.some( p => k in p && p[k] === o[k]), o;
});

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Hey, the first example should return `true` twice isn't it?

Comment: Well, no, I just made the first example return true or false based on wether or not all the objects in `b` are in `a`.